# How to create similar lists with only one differing element

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to create several lists where all except one element value are the same.
It easier to explain using an example, which I have provided below

```
list1 = [w,x,y,z]
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

I would want to return something like:

```
list3 = [[w,x,a,z],[w,x,b,z],[w,x,c,z],[w,x,d,z],[w,x,e,z],[w,x,f,z],[w,x,g,z]]
```

I tried to create a for loop to iterate over all values of list2 and take each ith element and replace a value in in list 1

```
index = 3
check_list = []
for i in list2: 
    list1.insert(list2[i],index)
    check_list.append(list1)
print(check_list)
```

When I try this I get the following error:
'Series' object has no attribute 'insert'

I believe this means that I may need to you use replace() instead of insert(). But I suspect I'm missing something else. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the error you mention. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Does the order of list1 matter? ie is the place of w,x,y, and z fixed?

Comment: Yes the order of matters, in this example w,x,and z should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the item of index 2 in each sub-list with items in another list, it can be done more conveniently to start off with the list of lists transposed first, assign the other list to index 2 of the list of lists, and then transpose it with `zip` for output:

```
list1 = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
list3 = [[i] * len(list2) for i in list1]
list3[2] = list2
list3 = list(map(list, zip(*list3)))
print(list3)
```

This outputs:

```
[['w', 'x', 'a', 'z'], ['w', 'x', 'b', 'z'], ['w', 'x', 'c', 'z'], ['w', 'x', 'd', 'z'], ['w', 'x', 'e', 'z'], ['w', 'x', 'f', 'z'], ['w', 'x', 'g', 'z']]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AttentiveIgnorantNotifications